# Iteration of List Items using selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver, click

I have a dropdown menu with 7 values and these 7 values are stored in the form of list items under unordered list as:

```
<ul class="rcbList" style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;zoom:1;">
   <li class="rcbItem ">--Select--</li>
   <li class="rcbHovered ">PIPL-C1-BH-RILJM</li>
   <li class="rcbItem ">PIPL-C1-BH1-RILJM</li>
   <li class="rcbItem ">PIPL-C1-BH2-RILJM</li>
   <li class="rcbItem ">PIPL-C1-BH-RPLJM</li>
   <li class="rcbItem ">PIPL-C1-DHJ-RPLJM</li>
   <li class="rcbItem ">PIPL-C1-DHJ-RILJM</li>
</ul>
```

I want to click on each value of this dropdown menu using `for` loop with the help of selenium chromedriver in python.
Suppose I want to click on 2nd value `PIPL-C1-BH-RILJM`, I can do it as :

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_rcmbCapacityTranch_DropDown']/div/ul/li[2]").click()
```

But to use it in the `for` loop, I have to do indexing on `li` tag. So, when I write as:

```
i=2
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_rcmbCapacityTranch_DropDown']/div/ul/li['+str(i)+']").click()
```

It shows only `--Select--` and does not select the 2nd value and same happens with other values of `i`.
I have also tried as:

```
i=2
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_rcmbCapacityTranch_DropDown']/div/ul/li['"+str(i)+"']").click()
```

But `--Select--` is selected again from the dropdown menu.
So, can anyone please help me to click on a particular value with indexing on `li` tag.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below once:

Collect all the `li` tag elements in a list and then iterate over them. Use `find_elements` for the same.

```
# This should highlight all the li tags - //div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_rcmbCapacityTranch_DropDown']/div/ul/li
options = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_rcmbCapacityTranch_DropDown']/div/ul/li")

# This should print 7
print(len(options))

# Start the loop from index 1 since the first option is "--Select--"
for i in range(1,len(options)):
    options[i].click()
```

Comment: Thank you @pmadhu.